# No [westminster] is better than a bad [westminster]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-renaming

The [westminster](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/westminster) has only 8 questions but they seem to cover different topics.

Few are about [the Westminster system of government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_system):

- [Is regular Prime Minister's Questions (PMQs) something unique to the Westminster system?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/61342)
- [To what extent do precedents in Westminster systems apply in other countries that use it?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/42053)
- [In Westminster systems that are not Australian is the term “Dorothy Dixer” known?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/50267)

Some are about the UK specifically:

- [The rules for cabinet and shadow cabinet membership in the UK?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/33028)
- [Is there an official/unoffiicial record kept of 'Three Line Whips' in UK Parliament?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/34354)
- [Are UK MPs sometimes obliged to say 'It is a pleasure to serve under your chairmanship'?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/43037)
- [What position & power does the Church of England assume in the upper house of Lords?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/56253)

One is mostly about a different topic (historic English influence on Scottish politics):

- [Scottish Politics; History of Sectarianism, Communism, Nationalism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/44399)

The tag excerpt isn't very descriptive either, it mostly introduces it as a synonym to [united-kingdom](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) (some tagret on whoever wrote that no doubt):

> Westminster is an area in Central London that's often used synonymously with the UK Government. Consider using with the following tags: [united-kingdom], [house-of-commons] or [house-of-lords].

---

My suggestion is as follows:

- Remove the tag from questions not about the [Westminster system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_system)
- Rename the tag to [westminster-system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/westminster-system)
- Add an excerpt that emphasizes the tag should be used when the question is about the Westminster system in general or comparing multiple implementations rather than one country's implementation (in which case the country tag suffices).
- Add the tag to other questions that fit this description. For example,

  - [In a Westminster system, why would the PM voluntarily dissolve a majority government?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/15531)
  - [Has there ever been a situation in a modern Westminster parliament where there have been more independents than members of the second largest party?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12199)
  - [Opposition members in cabinet](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/20619)
  - [Has a party that won an election ever lost its leader in the process?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/19855)